# to control the existence and distribution of meshes along x y z separately in ParametricPlot3D or SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions, mesh

I have a surface generated by the following code:

```
af = Pi/2; se = Sin[af/2] Sqrt[1 + Tan[Pi/2 - tt1]^2]; 
SphericalPlot3D[se, {tt1, 0, Pi}, {tt2, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[1]], PlotPoints -> 30, 
 Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #3 &}, ImageSize -> 600, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5 Pi, 1.5 Pi}, {-1.5 Pi, 1.5 Pi}, {-1 Pi, 1 Pi}}]
```

The figure looks like this.

[image]

What I want is that the meshes about the $z$ axis to be distributed evenly, but seems the code is distributing w.r.t. my spherical parameters. I wonder how can I realize this?

Moreover, I wonder if I can control the existence and the distribution of the meshes for x,y,z, or tt1 tt2? I think I should go to the meshfunction, but didn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: The reason that the mesh is distributed with respect to the spherical coordinate is that you told it to.  When you put `#4&` as one of the `MeshFunctions` you are telling it to place mesh with respect to the $\theta$ coordinate.   Look at the section on `MeshFunctions` in the documentation for `SphericalPlot3D` and you'll see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3noOO.png) which should explain what is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SphericalPlot3D[se, {tt1, 0, Pi}, {tt2, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[1]], PlotPoints -> 30, 
 Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Mesh -> {Range[-Pi, Pi , 2 Pi/10]}, MeshFunctions -> { #3 &}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5 Pi, 1.5 Pi}, {-1.5 Pi, 1.5 Pi}, {-1 Pi, 1 Pi}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi Kglr, this works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: @larry, i am glad it worked for you. Thank you for the Accept, and welcome to mma.se.